# Publish PreAuthentication trigger serverless AWS

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito, aws-serverless

Please I am facing an issue while trying to add a new trigger (Pre Authentication) Error Message on the pipeline as follows :

```
CognitoUserPoolMyUserPool - Role does not have permission to publish with SNS (
    Service: AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService;
    Status Code: 400;
    Error Code: InvalidSmsRoleAccessPolicyException;
    Request ID: 261e97e3-2106-44e1-a960-fd1d6325040f; Proxy: null
).
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add permissions to allow publishing to SNS